# How to get the SQL generated by Context.SubmitChanges in LINQ2SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, datacontext

Is there a way to get the SQL script that will be run when calling a Context.SubmitChanges()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Log property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the DataContext object can be assigned a [TextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that will be written to with the SQL generated by the request.

Also, see [www.linqpad.net](http://www.linqpad.net) for an awesome tool to help diagnose and test Linq-To-SQL queries which has a results window that shows what SQL was generated.